# How to turn i into a integer?

Tags: python

```
number = int(input("Search for: "))
upto = int(input("In range up to: "))
for i in range(upto):
   intv = int(v)
   if number in intv:
    print(i)
```

Need to make a program that finds numbers that have your number inside them.
Encountering a problem with the int not being iterable.

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: 1) `v` is not defined. 2) this code makes no sense. [ask]

Comment: `i` is already an integer in this code. The problem is that you can't test `if number in intv` when `intv` is an integer. It doesn't make sense in Python to ask if one number is `in` another number. Perhaps you could solve this problem by converting both numbers to strings?

Answer (score 1):

you can leave the number a string and then you can loop over the "characters", or digits

```
number = input("Search for: ")
upto = int(input("In range up to: "))
for i in range(upto):
    if number in str(i):
        print(i)
```